# Trying to solve this first-order nonlinear DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am really struggling with the next differential equation:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-xy}{x^2-x+y+e^y}.$$

So far I know it's a first-order nonlinear DE, but I cannot find a way to solve this. Any tip or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to substitute for $y$?

Comment: @Gerald I'm sorry, substitute for what?

Comment: *but I cannot find a way to solve this* You are in good company then. Neither Maple nor Mathematica can solve it. This is good sign this has no analytical solution.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but maybe this will help: sub $t=x-1.$ You get $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{yt}{t(t+1)+y+e^y}.$$ Change perspective to get $$\frac{dt}{dy}=-\frac{t(t+1)+y+e^y}{yt}.$$ Then if you sub $u=ty,$ you can get it down to $$-u\,\frac{du}{dy}=u+y^2+y\,e^y.$$ But there's no way to continue along those lines of which I am aware.

Comment: @Moo Yes, it is written correctly. It was part of an exam from my faculty.

Comment: I know this is late but the ODE would have been exact if it was $y'=\frac{y-2xy}{x^2-x+y+e^y}$. That way when we multiply by the denominator we get $f_y=x^2-x+y+e^y\implies f=y(x^2-x)+\frac{y^2}{2}+e^y+c(x)$ and $f_x=y(2x-1)\implies f=y(x^2-x)+c(y)$. Thus, $f=xy(x-1)+\frac{y^2}{2}+e^y$ and we can integrate the ODE to get: $xy(x-1)+\frac{y^2}{2}+e^y=c$. So I think the problem is written incorrectly.